# handle change input in an array reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of products like this:

```js
products = [
 {id: 'x1c', name: 'p1', quantity: 4},
 {id: 'cd1x', name: 'p2', quantity: 4},
 // more products ...
]
```

render products:

```js
products.map(product => {
  return <input value={product.quantity} />
});
```

How I can make state and can handle change a quantity of a product independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store an object with key-value pairs of productId-productQuantity

```js
const products = [
  { id: 'x1c', name: 'p1', quantity: 4 },
  { id: 'cd1x', name: 'p2', quantity: 4 }
]

const [productQuantity, setProductQuantity] = useState(
  products.reduce(
    (obj, product) => ({ ...obj, [product.id]: product.quantity }),
    {}
  )
)

products.map(product => {
  return (
    <input
      value={productQuantity[product.id]}
      onChange={e =>
        setProductQuantity({ ...productQuantity, [product.id]: e.target.value })
      }
    />
  )
})
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-lalande-hhcdb?file=/src/App.js) for demo

[image: Edit zealous-lalande-hhcdb]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i get you right but..

**Set products in state**

```
Const [product,setProduct] = useState({
    products:[
      {id: 'x1c', name: 'p1', quantity: 4},
      {id: 'cd1x', name: 'p2', quantity: 4},
      // more products ...
   ]
})
```

**List products **

```
function list(){
  product.products.map(product => 
   Return <p id={product.id}>{product.quantity}</p>
  )
}
```

**In render**

return ({list})

So if you add another product to array which is in state ,it should render it automatically.